# In the Validation Rules of a Model in ASP.NET MVC 3, how to add error messages translated in more languages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, class, model

When I add validation rules to a Model class, an error message can be added to it, however only in one language; how can I add error messages translated in more languages for a single property? 
Have I to write more class "copies" or exists a better method to implement it?

```
Public Class Movie
    Public Property ID() As Integer

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Title is required")>
    Public Property Title() As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Date is required")>
    Public Property ReleaseDate() As Date

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Genre must be specified")>
    Public Property Genre() As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Price Required"), Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage:="Price must be between $1 and $100")>
    Public Property Price() As Decimal

    <StringLength(5)>
    Public Property Rating() As String
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried using a resource file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName parameters to point to the resource file (.resx) with given string:

```
<Required(ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(Namespace.ResxFile),ErrorMessageResourceName:="GenreMustBeSpecified")>
Public Property Genre() As String
```

Then, You have to create one *.resx file for each language, like:

- ResxFile.resx - as default
- ResxFile.en-US.resx - english
- ResxFile.de-DE.res - german
- ...

Comment: thank you! I didn't know how to specify the reference to the file resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use a resource file and add your language code just before the .resx extension `Resources1.en-US.resx`

Then reference it

`[Required(ErrorMessage = MvcApplication1.Properties.Resources.ExampleResource)]`